# Memory leak with Out[]

Tags: memory

My understanding is that during evaluations in front end all the `Out[]`-s are in the memory, so they accumulate and at some point might cause *Mathematica* to crash. Is there a way to handle this issue? How to deallocate memory from all these output cells (printed and unprinted)?

Comment: Set `$HistoryLength=3` or something. By default, it is `Infinite` and keeps all the output.

Comment: Duplicate specifically of [(80978)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/80978/121)